# How can the Kalman filter be adapted to handle binary observations?

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, random-walks, hidden-markov-models

Imagine a coin with a time-varying probability of coming up heads.  (For example, perhaps the probability follows a random walk that is constrained to live in $[0, 1]$.  And say we have some information about how quickly we expect the true probability to vary over time (analogous to the standard deviation of the random walk described above).

At discrete time points, we are given data about the outcome of a given coin flip.  The goal is to come up with a robust procedure to estimate that probability over time.

This sounds like a task for a Kalman filter.  But the literature seems to assume that the observations will be normally distributed around a linear function of the state.  That feels quite violated by the assumptions above.

What's a reasonable way to proceed?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Could work around with log-likelihood. Can we get away with (0,1) instead?

Comment: @8none6, there is a general algorithm called sum-product (or max-product) or belief propagation, generalizing Kalman filters. See [for example](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wainwrig/Talks/A_GraphModel_Tutorial). What you describe sounds like a hidden markov model with a discrete observation, and you can use sum-product in this case too.

Comment: The extended Kalman filter works for any smooth (locally linear) generative model for your data, with the assumption of a gaussian and decorrelated noise.

Comment: Well, as per above, we're good on the locally linear model for the hidden variable.  But the whole point is to discuss a highly non-normal model for the noise on the observation process.

Answer (score 4):

In principle, this is what nonlinear filtering does. Check this out, also under the name "hidden Markov model". Particle filters can be adapted to deal with
this setup.

In a nutshell, here is what hidden Markov processes are.
You have a two component Markov chain $(X_n,Y_n)$ (I write it in discrete time, there is an analogue in continuous time). You observe only 
$\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and want to estimate $X_n$, i.e. construct the conditional pdf
of $X_n$ given the observations.

In your case, the law of $Y_n$ given the state history $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ depends only on $X_n$ and is a Bernoulli variable with mean depending on $X_n$.  $X_n$ itself is what you call $p$.

PS I just noted that my answer is closely related to that of @passerby51.

Comment: If you can point me to a resource that explains how to use this approach to solve my problem, I'll read up so I can consider accepting this answer...

Comment: https://global.oup.com/academic/product/the-oxford-handbook-of-nonlinear-filtering-9780199532902?cc=il&lang=en& has probably more information than you bargained for.

Comment: ...and if my bargaining skills are not at the top of their game, a higher price thanI bargained for, too!

Comment: Sure. Nobody buys these books except for select libraries. If you have no access, note that most articles are on arxiv.

Answer (score 2):

The Kalman filter is based on an assumption of Gaussian noise in both the observations and process. As I read your problem statement you have no observation noise. Given that, I don't think the KF is the correct choice.

"Yes, well, I'll just set the measurement noise to zero". The problem is that the KF performs the update step in measurement space. If you have no measurement noise, then you have no uncertainty in the normal to the measurement hyperplane. The system covariance ends up being singular (the math blows up).

Off the top of the head I don't know the correct approach to your question, but this does not sound like a KF application to me.

Comment: I don't agree with the statement that I have no measurement noise.  I flip a coin.  At that instant, it has a true probability `p` of coming up heads (which I do not know).  It comes up heads.  That doesn't mean `p=1.0`.  The outcome of the single coin toss should be assumed to be a draw from a probability distribution whose parameters are unknown and which we are trying to infer.

Comment: Put another way, my observations are not error-free...just they are distributed "very-non-normally" around their true value.

Comment: I see what you are saying. In your case _p_ is a hidden variable, and you regard a flip as a probabilistically distributed observation of _p_. But measurement noise in a KF is the noise in the _observed_ variable. I use a GPS to measure position, with error, then I can compute an unobserved variable, such as velocity. In your case the observed variable is the current flip, which you measure perfectly.

Comment: Sorry, I hit return. In the update step you work in measurement space, which means the measurement covariance is the error in the measurement of the _flip_, not the error in the sampling from the _state_.

Comment: I have no idea if the KF can be extended to your way of thinking - I work with them in Newtonian systems, where what I say very much applies. Particle filters do not require assumptions of linear systems or gaussian distributions, so if this is a fruitful line of thinking perhaps you'd be better served with one of them?

Comment: I'm not sure I see how there is a difference other than the shape of the error distribution.  The true state variable is p.  I measure p, but i get back a noisy reading.  The mean of my reading is p.  But the distribution around p is not normal (it is bimodal).  So I see this as a potential issue with distribution shape, rather than a broader philosophical difference.  No?

Answer (score 1):

What *I* would try when facing such a problem:

1°) Minimize $\lambda\int p'(t)^2\ dt +$ the sum of informations $\log (1/p(t_k))$ if heads at $t_k$, $\log (1/[1-p(t_k)])$ if tails.

2°) Chose $\lambda$ using (a suitable form of) cross-validation.

3°) Keep searching how people did before.

Answer (score 0):

Update: A 2019 paper on arXiv addresses this problem.

- Augusto Fasano, Giovanni Rebaudo, Daniele Durante, Sonia Petrone, [Exact Kalman filter for binary time series](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.06994), 2019.

Comment: Note the title of the arXiv paper was changed to "A closed-form filter for binary time series" in version 3.